# Nginx URL rewrite with static .html files for SEO

Tags: html, url-rewriting, nginx

I'm trying to setup a Nginx configuration for nice URLs without `.html` extension.

What I currently have works, but the `/` URI redirects to `/index` and I don't want that.

The URL rewrite rules should be as follows:

```
/index.html -> /
/test.html -> /test
/subpage/ -> /subpage
/subpage/test.html -> /subpage/test
/sub/sub/index.html -> /sub/sub
/sub/sub/ -> /sub/sub
/somepage/ -> /somepage
/somepage.html -> /somepage
```

Here is the configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    set $root /app/www/public;
    if (!-d /app/www/public) {
        set $root /config/www;
    }
    root $root;
    index index.html;
    
    error_page 401 /401;
    error_page 403 /403;
    error_page 404 /404;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500;
    
    location / {
        #redirect index.html to /
        if ( $request_uri ~ "index.html" ) {
            rewrite ^(.*)/ $1/ permanent;
        }

        #remove .html from request
        rewrite ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1 permanent;
        
        #remove the trailing /
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

        try_files $uri.html $uri/ $uri =404;
    }
    
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ {
       expires 30d;
    }
    location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
       expires 7d;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess/.htpasswd files
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

NOTE: this Nginx is running in a docker container.

Comment: Not sure if there is a directory /somepage/ and at the same time there is a somepage.html . Any advice on that?

Comment: I'll bet it is a problem with `if ( $request_uri ~ "index.html" )` because an `if` statement inside a `location` has non-obvious behavior: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Comment: Good point on the `if` statement. I'm pretty new to Nginx, coming from IIS there are a lot of things that are upside down from my point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with this configuration which I tested on nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu):

```
    index XXXXXX.DISABLE.INDEX.DOCUMENT.XXXXXX;
    location / {
        #remove index.html from request
        rewrite ^/(.*)/index(\.html)?$ /$1 permanent;    
        rewrite ^/(.*)index(\.html)?$ /$1 permanent;        

        #remove .html from request
        rewrite ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1 permanent;
        
        #remove the trailing /
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
        
        try_files $uri ${uri}/index.html ${uri}.html =404;
    }
```

By disabling the `index` functionality, you can handle add `index.html` to the `try_files` which is more compatible with the rewrite rules.

You can control if `/sub/index.html` or `/sub.html` takes precedence for a request for `/sub` by changing the order of `${uri}/index.html` and `${uri}.html` in `try_files`.

Tests:

- `curl --head http://localhost/` -> `200 OK` (powered by `/index.html`)
- `curl --head http://localhost/index` -> `301 Moved Permanently` to `Location: http://localhost/`
- `curl --head http://localhost/index.html` -> `301 Moved Permanently` to `Location: http://localhost/`
- `curl --head http://localhost/page` -> `200 OK` (powered by `/page.html`)
- `curl --head http://localhost/page.html` -> `301 Moved Permanently` to `Location: http://localhost/page`
- `curl --head http://localhost/sub` -> `200 OK` (powered by `/sub/index.html`)
- `curl --head http://localhost/sub/` -> `301 Moved Permanently` to `Location: http://localhost/sub`
- `curl --head http://localhost/sub/` -> `301 Moved Permanently` to `Location: http://localhost/sub`
- `curl --head http://localhost/sub/index` -> `301 Moved Permanently` to `Location: http://localhost/sub`
- `curl --head http://localhost/sub/index.html` -> `301 Moved Permanently` to `Location: http://localhost/sub`

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: is there a difference between `${uri}` and `$uri` ?

Comment: No. Using the curly braces allows you to use it next to other letters, but in this case there are punctuation separators so it doesn't matter